# ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Tags: c#, oracle11g

When I execute a delete storedprocedure I am getting "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation".

And also it takes time (about more than 10 seconds) to throw exception from the application

when I execute this query in Toad it takes more than 30 seconds, when i cancel it, in the output windows, it shows above error.

I think, dataaccess blog is cancels automatically when it exeeds the timeout.

I am wondering why it takes 30 seconds. And when I run the select query alone, there are no records.

When I call delete only it takes time.

```
DELETE FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM VoyageVesselBunkers a
       JOIN VoyageVessel b
       ON  a.VoyageVesselId = b.Id
       WHERE a.Id    = NVL(null,a.Id)
       AND  b.VoyageId   = NVL('5dd6a8fbb69d4969b27d01e6c6245094',b.VoyageId)
       AND  a.VoyageVesselId = NVL(null,a.VoyageVesselId) );
```

any suggestion.
anand

Comment: Can we see code and the full error?

Comment: updated the code and full error

Comment: Is it always the same line in the stored procedure? Can you please show the code of the stored procedure `POSITIONCONSUMPTION_PK`?

Comment: above query throws error. select works fine, only delete fires the error.

Answer (score 5):

If you have *uncommitted* changes to a data row sitting in a SQL editor (such as SQL Developer, Oracle, etc.), and you try to update the same row via another program (perhaps one that is running in an IDE such as Visual Studio), you will also get this error. To remedy this possible symptom, simply commit the change in the SQL editor.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is setting a timeout (`storedProcCommand.CommandTimeout`).  The error indicates that the stored procedure call is taking longer than the allowed timeout will allow so it is cancelled.  You would either need to increase (or remove) the timeout or you would need to address whatever performance issue is causing the procedure call to exceed the allowed timeout.

Answer (score -4):

ORA-01013   user   requested   cancel   of   current   operation

Cause:   The   user   interrupted   an   Oracle   operation   by   entering   CTRL-C,   Control-C,   or   another
canceling   operation.   This   forces   the   current   operation   to   end.   This   is   an   informational
message   only.

Action:   Continue   with   the   next   operation.

Comment: This just copies and pastes the error definition. It's not really an answer to the OPs problem.